# Please explain what is happening in this piece of code in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

> `Javascript` code:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  console.log(i);
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(" magic "+ i)
  }, 2000);

};
```

> outputs:

[image: output]

1. What does the number `25` mean ?
2. How `i` was incremented  to `5` while `i++` is unreachable after `4`?

Answer (score 0):

You get the numbers 0 to 4 from:

```
console.log(i);
```

and 5 times "magic 5" because you execute

```
console.log(" magic "+ i)
```

5 times after you counted `i` to 5.

The more interesting part is the other number. This is the result from the last `setTimeout(...)`. Everytime you execute Javascript in the console you get the  return value of your code (`console.log("foo")` would yield `undefined`). The last statement directly executed in your code is a `setTimeout` which returns an ID.